# manipulating nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset provided as nested dictionaries within a dictionary. I have been able to extract each dictionary from the main dictionary and the data looks like this;

A key with a value which is a list of nested dictionaries.

- The key is a sensor_id
- 'ts' is a timestamp that I need to convert back to a DateTime.
- 'v' is the value or reading at the associated timestamp

2220_1: [{'ts': 1577865600000, 'v': 47.5}, {'ts': 1577866500000, 'v': 46}, {'ts': 1577867400000, 'v': 47}, {'ts': 1577868300000, 'v': 44}]

2221_1: [{'ts': 1577865600000, 'v': 49}, {'ts': 1577866500000, 'v': 47}, {'ts': 1577867400000, 'v': 48}, {'ts': 1577868300000, 'v': 45}]

2222_1: [{'ts': 1577865600000, 'v': 50}, {'ts': 1577866500000, 'v': 52}, {'ts': 1577867400000, 'v': 51}, {'ts': 1577868300000, 'v': 50.5}]

I am trying to find a way of manipulating the dictionaries into a dataframe that would look something like this

```
"""

     DateTime           2220_1    2221_1    2222_1
     01/01/2017 00:00    47.5       49       50
     01/01/2017 00:15    46         47       52
     01/01/2017 00:30    47         48       51
     01/01/2017 00:45    44         45      50.5
```

"""

I am struggling a little at the moment with dictionaries in general and hope that somebody might be able to point me in the right direction with this

Thanks

Comment: Sorry .. I have been editing the post as my first attempt showed a poor example of my hoped for output

Comment: Panda's data frame constructor documentation is a good place to start. One way to do it could be to extract ts values into a list (DateTime) and use it as index ("row ids") and a somewhat transformed dictionary you have as data. Check this in repl: 
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[datetime(2000,1,1),datetime(2000,1,2)], data = { '2200_1': [47.5, 46], '2221_1':[49,47]}) , with from datetime import datetime (just for this simple example, pandas has its own date time handling as well)
There might a simpler way as well, but that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v)
             .set_index('ts')
             .rename(columns={'v':k}) for k,v in d.items()],
          axis=1)

df.index=df.index.map(datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

Output:

```
                   2220_1  2221_1  2222_1
ts                                   
01/01/2017 00:00    47.5      49    50.0
01/01/2017 00:15    46.0      47    52.0
01/01/2017 00:30    47.0      48    51.0
01/01/2017 00:45    44.0      45    50.5
```

Comment: Your missing `for` on line 4

Comment: Thank you .. has done exactly what I wanted. I will try and understand the logic behind this. You seem to be passing the values into pd.DataFrame(v) and axis = 1 works along the columns? Very elegant

Answer (score 1):

@TrevP has the best answer (so far), but since I'd already written it, here is a pure-python refactoring of your origional dictionary:

```py
d_refactored = {k:{i['ts']:i['v'] for i in v} for k,v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_refactored)
df.index /= 1000.
df.index=df.index.map(datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for this .. another very useful answer. Printing out after the second line gives me what I was after. I can't quite make the df.index=df.index.map(datetime.fromtimestamp) line work however. I have the datetime library imported. Is a parameter missing in this line?  Cheers

Comment: Ah the argument for `fometimestamp` is in seconds, while `ts` is in milliseconds. I've added `df.index /= 1000.` to account for this.